Primeng timeline component working badly in Angular

Trying to use PrimeNG timeline, the component is shown but the line and dots does not appear. I currently use Google Chrome, Angular 16.2.0 and primeNg 17.2.0.
The console does not show any error at all. I also use Angular Material for the rest of components but doesnt appear to be that kind of error (collision between libraries I mean).
Any thoughts?
Template:

Component:


Did you import and load the relevant styles? PrimeNG comes with a set of CSS files that need to be loaded in a specific way for it to look usable

I did not... it had to be some basic sh*t as I do not use primeNg from scratch for a long time. Solved and closing, Thanks @Shahar.
